# How we get data from 1:Array(10)

Tags: javascript

Basically I have to list all video which are in 1:Array(10). and I'm unable to get data from this so please help me

```
Object {1: Array(10), message: "Get all category list", status: "200", result: Array(1)}
```

Comment: try object[0] ? or object["1"]

Comment: I don't think there is anything in `Array(10)`. The syntax simply creates an Array of 10 `undefined` values.

Comment: Where is that Object coming from anyway?

Answer (score 2):

If your property is named 1, than you will not be able to do `Object.1` . However, you can do this `Object["1"]`

Answer (score 2):

You have an object as a parameter so just:

```
const array = obj['1'];
array.forEach( item => {
    //do something here
});
```